# Jplayer Share Button - Pulling Parameter from URL

Tags: jquery, jplayer, url-parameters

I have a jplayer with playlist that loads from an xml file and is transformed into json. I am trying to add a share button (just a central one, not on each song in the playlist) and while i have successfully created the code that will add the title to the URL for sharing, I cannot figure out how to pull the parameter off of the URL to make sure the shared song is played when a user follows the link the site. I am modifying the playlist file, specifically the select function. My site is local so I can't share a link but I can post the modified portion of the playlist code.

Thanks for any help you can give me!!
Steph

[Link to original playlist file](https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/blob/master/add-on/jplayer.playlist.js)

Modified select function:

```
    select: function(index) {
    $.urlParam = function(homily) {
            var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + homily + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
            return results[1] || 0;
            console.log($.urlParam('homily'));
        index = (index < 0) ? this.original.length + index : index; // Negative index relates to end of array.
        if(encodeURIComponent($.urlParam('homily')) === this.playlist[index].title) {
        this.current = this.playlist[index].title;
        $(this.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("setMedia", this.playlist[this.current]);
        } else if (0 <= index && index < this.playlist.length) {
            this.current = index;
            this._highlight(index);
            $(this.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("setMedia", this.playlist[this.current]);
        var downloadBtn=this.cssSelector.cssSelectorAncestor+' [class^="download_btn"]';
            $(downloadBtn).attr('href', encodeURIComponent(this.playlist[this.current].mp3));
            var shareBtn=this.cssSelector.cssSelectorAncestor+' [class^="share_btn"]';
            $(shareBtn).attr('href', "?homily=" + decodeURIComponent(this.playlist[this.current].title));

        } else {
            this.current = 0;           
    }
    }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need to generate a URL, based on current media and also you want to know which media is currently played if played at all. Right?

Ok then, here are some thoughts:

- JPlayerPlaylist add-on has an internal property `this.current` (here and further `this` is used in context of a playlist object), which will store an index of currently selected/played media. To get that object you would access `this.playlist[this.current]`. You already are doing something along this lines in the code, which you provided.
- If you want to know a state of a player at some particular time. Easiest way would be to access `$("#your_jPlayer_Id").data("jPlayer").status.paused`, which will return `true` if player is paused.
- I would also added some statements to `play` and `pause` methods, like setting button's `href` to `#` on pause and restoring it back to the valid URL on `play`.